# Is it possible to get IP address of SSH/SFTP client via Apache Mina SSHD ServerSession?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, apache-mina

I create SFTP server using Apache Mina SSHD. I want to find out the client IP when they connect to my server (via FileZilla, WinSCP). However, while I tried to found it in `ServerSession`, I could not.

Where can I find this information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ServerSession.getIoSession` to retrieve an `IoSession` instance. And on that, call `IoSession.getRemoteAddress()`:

```
serverSession.getIoSession().getRemoteAddress()
```